Dimensional analysis with series
Lets say I have the following series:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}$$
and that the units of $a_i$ are [A] and the units of $b_i$ are [B]. Is the following correct?:
$$\frac{[A][B]}{[A]} = [B]$$
That is, are the resulting units B units?

It doesn't make sense to divide by the index of the sum outside of the sum.

I don't quite understand your sum, but your equation is correct. For example, consider the center of mass $\sum_{i}{m_{i}\mathbf{r}{i}}/\sum{i}{m_{i}}$. It has units of length (as we would expect) because the numerator has units of mass times length and the denominator has units of mass.

Yes, I am sorry! I meant to put the summation in the denominator too. I edited my question to correct for this. @kandb is the dimensional analysis still correct?

@SantiagoValdivieso Yes, it is! It's the same form as the example I included.
